# Use column named using 'AS' clause in next column definition

Tags: sql, postgresql, where-clause, column-alias

How would I use the column I defined as 'total_affected' in place of the long function?.. I feel like there is a better way to do this rather than to repeat the same thing from the previous line. I am not sure how to define it so I can use it right after in the next column.

```sql
SELECT c.name,
       COALESCE(sum(country_status_count.cured), 0) as cured,
       COALESCE(sum(country_status_count.dead), 0) as dead,
       cic.infected,
       SUM(COALESCE(cured, 0) + COALESCE(dead, 0) + infected) AS total_affected,
       (total_affected / c.population) as rate_of_infection <-- Something like this line instead of copying the whole function from the line above


FROM country_status_count

RIGHT JOIN country c ON country_status_count.country_id = c.id
RIGHT JOIN country_infection_counts cic ON c.name = cic.name

GROUP BY c.name, cic.infected, c.population
ORDER BY c.name ASC;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use either a CTE to set the dataset before applying the division or duplicate the `SUM()` clause in the division.

```
WITH dataset AS
(
    SELECT c.name
         , COALESCE(sum(country_status_count.cured), 0) as cured
         , COALESCE(sum(country_status_count.dead), 0) as dead
         , cic.infected
         , SUM(COALESCE(cured, 0) + COALESCE(dead, 0) + infected) AS total_affected
         , c.population
      FROM country_status_count
     RIGHT JOIN country c ON country_status_count.country_id = c.id
     RIGHT JOIN country_infection_counts cic ON c.name = cic.name
     GROUP BY c.name, cic.infected
     ORDER BY c.name ASC;
)
SELECT *
     , (total_affected / population) as rate_of_infection <-- Something like this line
  FROM dataset
;
```

Or:

```
SELECT c.name
     , COALESCE(sum(country_status_count.cured), 0) as cured
     , COALESCE(sum(country_status_count.dead), 0) as dead
     , cic.infected
     , SUM(COALESCE(cured, 0) + COALESCE(dead, 0) + infected) AS total_affected
     , (SUM(COALESCE(cured, 0) + COALESCE(dead, 0) + infected)/ c.population) as rate_of_infection
  FROM country_status_count
 RIGHT JOIN country c ON country_status_count.country_id = c.id
 RIGHT JOIN country_infection_counts cic ON c.name = cic.name
 GROUP BY c.name, cic.infected, c.population
 ORDER BY c.name ASC
;
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the column `c.population` in the `GROUP BY` clause and reuse `SUM(COALESCE(cured, 0) + COALESCE(dead, 0) + infected)` for the calculation, because you can't use the derived column `total_affected`:

```
SELECT c.name,
       COALESCE(sum(country_status_count.cured), 0) as cured,
       COALESCE(sum(country_status_count.dead), 0) as dead,
       cic.infected,
       SUM(COALESCE(cured, 0) + COALESCE(dead, 0) + infected) AS total_affected,
       (SUM(COALESCE(cured, 0) + COALESCE(dead, 0) + infected) / c.population) as rate_of_infection 
FROM country_status_count
RIGHT JOIN country c ON country_status_count.country_id = c.id
RIGHT JOIN country_infection_counts cic ON c.name = cic.name
GROUP BY c.name, c.population, cic.infected
ORDER BY c.name ASC;
```